# How to add checkbox into listview dynamically from a database in table form?

Tags: java, database, android-studio, checkbox, android-listview

I am creating a list of checkbox, the data is coming from the database. The checkbox is rendering dynamically. But the problem is, the list is either coming in horizontal direction or in vertical direction. I want to make the list in table form.
[image]
[image]

```
 stateManager.Instance.getDefectListFromServer(new ICallback() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            defectArrayList = stateManager.Instance.defectList;

            for (Defect defect:defectArrayList) {
                final CheckBox frontButton = new CheckBox(instance);
                frontButton.setText(defect.name);
                frontButton.setTag(defect);
                frontButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        instance.onCheckboxClicked(v);
                    }
                });
                switch (defect.type)
                {
                    case Front:
                        frontList.addView(frontButton);
                        break;
                    case Lining:
                        liningList.addView(frontButton);
                        break;
                    case Sleeve:
                        sleeveList.addView(frontButton);
                        break;
                    case Assembly:
                        assemblyList.addView(frontButton);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to view the checkboxes in tabular format? Could you please add a sample view?

Comment: @NipunaPriyamal I have added the screenshot of my application. As you can see there is a scrollview, in which a list of checkboxes are there. Now, they are getting render with the use of database data. It is displaying in vertically. I want to display these data in tabular form. For example:

XYZ       |      XXX      |     YYY   |     ZZZ    |    CCC   |   AAA

Comment: @NipunaPriyamal, I have also added the sample in the image, how I want the output.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert Please find it in the description.